# How to trigger the coffeescript on infinite-scroll loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am working on product listing page more products are loaded with infinite scroll. The problem is when the new page is loaded, the on click event on the 'thumbnail of the product' on the loaded page will not execute. By clicking the thumbnails image of the product,the images must swap. 
The Carousel i have used here is the jcarousel.

Thanks in Advance

## Infinite Scroll:

```
$(document).ready ->
 $("#home-products").infinitescroll
 navSelector: "nav.pagination" 
 nextSelector: "nav.pagination a[rel=next]" 
 itemSelector: "#home-products #products"
```

Below is the onclick function which is to be executed in the newly loaded page

```
$('.product .v-color').on 'click', (e)->
e.preventDefault()
$this = $(@)
$product = $this.closest('.product')
$product.find('.v-color').removeClass('active')
number = $this.data('carousel-number')
$product.find('.carousel').carousel(number)
$this.addClass('active')
changePrice($product, $this.data('price'), $this.data('soldout'), 
$this.data('backorderable'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by changing the onclick function as below:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.product .v-color', (e)->
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe yoour problem is connected to turbolinks, the `$(document).ready` event is not triggered with turbolinks, because there is no actual page reload if the page was cached from the browser. The event you need to use is

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
   // you js code
})
```

this is the [turbolinks 5 documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads) if you want to check info. I am just making assumptions, can not really be sure what is your actual problem, but the problem is caused from your `event` not being triggered after the page reload so it makes sense